# 'External table is not in the expected format.' when reading excel(.xlsx) file which is saving in 2010 format?

Tags: excel, oledb

when i am reading excel(2010) file, "External table is not in the expected format." error occurs. i am using Oledb connection to read excel file.please provide me best solution for this issue. thank you...

```
        string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES'";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                string firstSheet = "";
                int count = dtExcelSchema.Rows.Count;
                conn.Close();
                //Read Data from First Sheet
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                var tempDataTable = (from dataRow in dtExcelSchema.AsEnumerable()
                                     where !dataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase")
                                     select dataRow).CopyToDataTable();
                dt = tempDataTable;
                firstSheet = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                if (!firstSheet.EndsWith("$"))
                {
                    firstSheet = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "$";
                }
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + firstSheet + "]";
                string query1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM [" + firstSheet + "]";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(query1, conn);
                cmd.CommandText = query1;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
                {
                    string sheetName = firstSheet.Replace(" ", "").Replace("'", "");
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                    dtnew.TableName = firstSheet;
                    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    oda.Fill(dtnew);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Kindly add the code which you've tried so far, and add the tags apropriately

Comment: any updates@Spidey

Comment: when i upload 2007 format excel file, my code works  but this code doesn't work for excel 2010.